# JSON Layout outputting json content inside a div

Tags: sxa, json

Using a Sitecore 9.1.1 site with SXA 1.8.1 - I added a new page and changed the Layout via Presentation Details to use the JSON Layout option.  I was then able to open in experience editor and see the JSON items in the toolbox.

I added JSON Content to my page and published it.
[image]

If I view this URL in a browser I see this on the page:
[image]

It looks like it's outputting the row div due to the placeholder which I don't want, AND it's not just showing the content string incorrectly.  Am I doing something wrong?

I was anticipating I could add JSON content to a page to expose data in a JSON structure to be used by another consumer.

Update:
So initially I couldn't select the JSON device in the Experience tab, but the second time around it worked.

[image: Initial view which didn't work]

So if I do that before adding the JSON content rendering and not touch the layout in Presentation details I don't get that div.  However, if I edit the content inline on the experience editor page it wraps the content in a paragraph tag.

So after editing HTML and removing the paragraph tag:
[image]

Are you not supposed to experience edit the JSON content fields?  Either way, I still need to get rid of this `<pre>..</pre>` element.

Comment: I do not recall such issues but it looks like a bug on the 1.8.1. It is working fine on the latest code. Can you upgrade?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski not an option at the moment. Will add more info to the question.

Comment: You need to switch to preview/normal mode on the JSON device to get rid of Experience Editor markup.